# Hibernate Criteria with projection: how to group by / get the main entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have an `Entity` class mapped with a 1-N association with `AnotherEntity` class, and I want to perform a query to get entities with some restrictions alongside the maximum `n` property of the `AnotherEntity` objects associated with them.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Entity.class, "e");
c.createAlias("e.anotherEntitySet", "otherEntities");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("someEntityProperty", someEntityPropertyValue));
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.max("otherEntities.n"));
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("pk"));
c.setProjection(projectionList);
List resultList = c.list();
```

The problem is that `resultList` is filled by `Object[]` elements containing the maximum `n` and the `pk` property of entities. While I want the maximum `n`, I don't want just the `pk` property: I want the whole `Entity` objects.

How can I obtain them, and still performing a single query in the process?

Comment: I guess you should do it by using a view extending the Entity object and with a new property `n`

Comment: @AngeloImmediata will it work just by adding the proper result transformer mapping to a view bean, or do I need to add projection properties for each Entity property one by one?

Comment: You can create the view and a hibernate entity mapping the view. Then  you can handle it like a normal hibernate entity no need to add projections and so on...